# Create live product feed for partner site

Tags: magento-1.9, database, products

I want to create live feed for my partner site where he can show all my products according to need.

- One way is that I export products and give file but in this way he will not be display new products added on my site.

Requirement: Do I need to create xml or json api OR what I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Magento comes out of the box with a fully functional WSDL & Rest API that also includes calls for the catalog. Just make sure you set the right role under `System > Webservices > SOAP/XML user roles` so they can only READ and not WRITE or UPDATE anything and you're good to go!

Documentation on the webservices can be found [on the Magento site](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalog.html).

One minor detail tho. Having a partner site use your API to display product information means the server will be queried heavily. For each pageview he has you'll also get a request to your API generating load on both the webserver and the database. Keep that in mind when you give this out to 5 or 10+ partners